# in laravel homstead project npm install get error

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, breeze, laravel-jetstream

My operating system is windows 10. I'm using laravel homestead (ubuntu 18.04) resent release and working in a virtual box with vagrant. After installing Laravel when I try to run:

`composer require laravel/breeze --dev`

to get the Authenticate part it works fine. after that, it says to run `npm install && npm run dev`

Then I CD to my test.com project and ran that command

after install, some features below error appears.
(I get the same issue when I try to require jetstream )

I used my Git bash shell as admin. I did re-run npm, npm clear cash force, remove package.json but still having the same problem.

sudo npm install says some permission problem in the host computer.

Actually, I'm Stuck. Please help

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT<br>
npm ERR! syscall open<br>
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/code/test.com/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/yargs-parser/
package.json.1050278784
npm ERR! errno -2<br>
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/test.com/no
de_modules/yargs/node_modules/yargs-parser/package.json.1050278784'<br>
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.<br>
npm ERR! enoent<br>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:<br>
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2020-12-20T04_04_37_652Z-debug.log<br>
vagrant@homestead:~/code/test.com$ cd /
```

Comment: Have you try to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then issue `npm install` again?

Comment: yes, but the same error come again

Comment: Why do you go to root location in last line i.e. `cd /`?

Comment: I just copied the error after some commands. That line is not necessary.

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Did you ever find a solution?